# Insert picture into MS Outlook less than window size?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook

I'm running Microsoft Windows 10 Pro  & Office 365-Outlook v1907.

**Is there a way to have pictures inserted into emails sized to fit the email message window?** Ideally, 80% of window size.

This is what I get when I insert a screen grab,

[image]

This is what I want,

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can change the visible size of the picture without changing its file size
or resolution and without shrinking the total size of the email message.

You should use the small circular sizing handles found at each corner of the picture.
If the handles are not visible, click on the picture for them to appear.

Drag one of four cornet handles toward the center to reduce the display of the image.
If some handles are not visible, use the ones that are visible.

The sizing handles in the center of each side of the picture will distort the picture
by changing only one axe, so making it smaller only horizontally or only
vertically.

Alternatively, on the *Format* tab, in the *Size* group, enter the required height.
The width will change automatically in proportion to the height.

---

It is also possible to compress the picture's size.
This will maintain the height and width but will reduce the resolution.
The picture will have a smaller file size but also a picture of lower quality.

This is done using *Picture Tools* on the *Format* tab, selecting
*Compress Pictures* from the *Adjust* group. Depending on your screen resolution, you may only see the Compress Pictures icon.

[image]

Source:
[Reduce the size of pictures and attachments in Outlook email messages](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/reduce-the-size-of-pictures-and-attachments-in-outlook-email-messages-d0b6b6bf-3b08-4dad-a01c-533719d1c005).

---

EDIT: I think I found a way of forcing a default size for the picture:

- Insert any picture into a new mail and use the handles to reduce its size
- While the picture is still selected, use the ribbon
  *Insert > Quick Parts > Save Selection to Quick Part Gallery...*
  and give it a name
- From now on, to add an image, first insert this quick part via
  *Insert > Quick Parts > Click the picture*
- Then right-click the picture and select "Change Picture* to select
  a new picture
- The new picture will keep the same dimensions as the previous one.

  [image]

Comment: +1 for Format > Size. I'm inserting screen grabs frequently and the sizing handles requires me to do a lot of scroll, grab the handle and then it's hold on as my trackpad mouse shrinks the image too fast, flips orientation, and generally makes me go mad as a hatter. That said, I wish the default would be to make all images fit the size of the window, and only, if I need it bigger, should I have to resize using this method. That just seems *sane* default for (business) email.

Comment: I think I had an idea, added at the end. Try to see if it works for you.

Comment: QuickParts saves images and settings for inserting the same image into other emails. That's cool and new to me. And I see what you're suggesting. Put a placeholder, then replace it. We need "paste style" here.

Comment: Paste style would be good, but doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: harry's answer is the nearest one, there's not a solution that totally matches it.

Answer (score -1):

What tool do you use to create the image?
Can you save it first as a PNG file and then insert?  Does this work?

I have some PNG images made with SnagIT (Techsmith) and small files take about 1/3 of the message window across. So this is an alternative way for you.

Of course, size depends upon the size of the image but you can adjust the size of a PNG image with an image editor

Comment: I use *Snippet Tool*.

Comment: Can you save the picture, edit the size and then insert into Outlook.  IrfanView is a free picture editor that can change sizes